# Assign value to struct in C

Tags: c, struct, strcpy

I'm building a game, and when I change the value in 2d-map using the following code

```
char example[100];
strcpy(example, " ");
strcat(example, player1->unitName[j]);
strcat(example, " ");
map->map[x][y] = example;
```

the whole values I put with example in map change.

I guess I'm putting the pointer to the example.

Is there any way I can put just the value of example not the address or pointer?

Comment: Allocate buffer and copy the contents to it. `strdup()` will be convenient if available.

Comment: Can you show me how to use strdup() in this case.. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should allocate new buffer for each elements and copy the contents like this.

```
char example[100], *buffer;
strcpy(example, " ");
strcat(example, player1->unitName[j]);
strcat(example, " ");
buffer = malloc(strlen(example) + 1); /* +1 for terminating null-character */
if (buffer != NULL) {
    strcpy(buffer, example);
} else {
    /* handle error */
}
map->map[x][y] = buffer;
```

You can use [`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) if it is available in your system.

```
char example[100];
strcpy(example, " ");
strcat(example, player1->unitName[j]);
strcat(example, " ");
map->map[x][y] = strdup(example);
```

Comment: +1. Don't forget to free the memory. Another example would be to have a three dimensional array: `map->map[x][y][100] = "Who's your daddy?";`. But of course, this is considered a bad practice due to memory wasting.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Not knowing the actual definition, your example looks like performing out-of-range access and meaningless pointer-to-integer conversion. Shouldn't it be `strcpy(map->map[x][y], "Who's your daddy?");`?

Comment: Oops. Apologies. Too much Python at work. Started to mess things up :)